# PBJVision switch to front facing camera

Tags: swift, pbjvision

Hi I am trying to switch between the rear and front facing cameras if i start he session with the front facing camera it works but with the other way way round the AVCapturepreview layer is not visible and just presents a blank screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First stop the preview session.
When stopped (use the delegate for this) set the camera device you want and restart the preview session.
In code:

```
[[PBJVision sharedInstance] stopPreview];
//implement the following deluge ate
- (void)visionSessionDidStopPreview:(PBJVision *)vision{

vision.cameraDevice = PBJCameraDeviceFront;
[vision startPreview];
}
```